# When can an automorphism of a group (as a set) be identified as action of some elements in the group?

Tags: group-theory

Let's suppose we have a group $G$ and a set function $\phi: G \to G$, what are some characterizing conditions for when the action of this function can be written as action of some elements in the group? eg: $\phi(g) = ag$  or $\phi(g)$ for some $ a \in G$, $\phi(g) = agb$, for $b \in G$

## My thoughts

So, far it's clear to me that at the very least, $\phi$ must be a set bijection.

Comment: Well, it has to be a bijection by similar reasoning.   And of course the map $F(g)=\phi(g)g^{-1}$ must be a constant.

Comment: You might also consider what element the identify $e\in G$ gets mapped to.  I suspect you will immediately deduce what possibilities $a\in G$ exist.

Comment: For any automorphism $\phi$ then $\phi(e)=e$.  That means only the identity automorphism can be modeled this way. If you want more automorphism you'll need to consider the conjugate action to find the inner automorphism.

Comment: Why is it important if it's constant? @lulu

Comment: What do you mean?  You asked for properties your function had to satisfy and that's one.  That one characterizes left multiplication, of course.

Comment: Hmm, but I don't see how exactly it constraints the possibilities for such functions which can be realized as elements. Maybe I am missing something

Comment: Would $\phi(g)=aga^{-1}$ fit either?

Comment: I'll try again, so how the function shuffles the group elements should be writable as the group element left and right multiplied with some elements @Devo

Answer (score 1):

Given a group $G$ and a map $φ \colon G \to G$, the following two conditions are equivalent:

1. $φ$ is given by left-multiplication with some element of $G$, i.e., there exists an element $a$ of $G$ with $φ(g) = ag$ for every $g ∈ G$.
2. $φ$ is a homomorphism of right $G$-sets, i.e., $φ(xg) = φ(x)g$ for all $x, g ∈ G$.

Indeed, if the first condition is satisfied, then
$$
  φ(xg) = a x g = φ(x) g \,.
$$
If the setting condition is satisfied, then for $a ≔ φ(e)$ we have
$$
  φ(g) = φ(eg) = φ(e)g = ag \,.
$$

If one (and thus both) of these equivalent conditions are satisfied, then $φ$ is automatically bijective.

Comment: This came a bit early. I think I may have not been able to explain my question well enough, I tried to elaborate again in the post and comments now.